# Can you import Stock Options data into Google Sheets

Tags: function

I'm trying to create Stock Options watchlist in Google sheet but its not working. Let's say I need to pull AMZN Jun 4000 Option (AMZN220617C04000000) Bid price in to google sheet but I get an error "resource at url not found"

=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote",AMZN220617C04000000,"?p=",AMZN220617C04000000,""""),"//tr[bid]"))

Is there an option to make this work ? Or can this be possible in MS Excel running on Mac?

Thank you for your time and Support

Comment: I don't understand your formula which sould be CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote","?p=","AMZN220617C04000000")

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch data with importxml in this case because the webpage is built by javascript on your side and not on the server side. Nevertheless, all the data is available in a json which you can get this way

```
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

you can then get informations you need from 'data'
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sTA71PhpxI_QdGKXVAtb0Rc3cmvPLgzvXKXXTmiec7k/copy

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and see if that helps. Thank you for the quick response.